# Flash 11 in IE9 randomly doen't load larger .jpg files

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer

Something strange started to happen when we tested our game on IE9. As in the topic we are loading a rather large .jpg file (1.7 mb) as a background for the game. But really randomly that file doesn't load.

We noticed that it happens more often after a longer playing session when IE starts to use more and more system resources. But there's no rule in this unfortunately. Only users of a x64 Windows system reported such problems, maybe it can be helpful.

Had anyone came across such issues in his own project? I'm looking for any possible source of help because it's an important task to solve before wider tests.

Comment: What error is being reported by the loader?

Comment: Loader doesn't report any errors. The .jpg file starts to load, it takes more and more memory but doesn't throw anything, neither the server replies with an error.

Comment: You are listening to all the event handlers correctly, and reporting any errors they may spit out? Catching exceptions won't work for asynchronous errors. Even if it's an IE only issue, it should report an error.

Comment: Ok, I found a place where I can put some more logs, we will check if this makes me find the problem, thanks for now.

Comment: Have you run a http debugger, confident the request is being sent out?

Comment: We have only a test report from a tester, I personally haven't even once encountered such an issue. The debugger was attached and in fact the request was sent.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your images too big so Event.COMPLETE does not fire after loading.

> In AIR 1.5 and Flash Player 10, the maximum size for a BitmapData
>   object is 8,191 pixels in width or height, and the total number of
>   pixels cannot exceed 16,777,215 pixels. (So, if a BitmapData object is
>   8,191 pixels wide, it can only be 2,048 pixels high.) In Flash Player
>   9 and earlier and AIR 1.1 and earlier, the limitation is 2,880 pixels
>   in height and 2,880 in width.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

I had the same issue recently.

Comment: Not really, I checked it firstly because we had such problem in the past. Besides, this a random occasion so why sometimes the file loades and sometimes not? It's out first time we use such large image files but we are aware of all constraints on size of that file so it doesn't seem like a solution for this problem.